# search query + post data from Zomato api

Tags: javascript

Another person on this site was able to help me get an idea on how to post data from jsonplaceholder. But im trying to figure out how to POST data from the zomato api, as I want to simulate an app that does a search query and posts data based upon an input, but for example, if i search "bethesda" im unsure what url I would need to fetch. would the parameters in the documentation all need to be in the url? just confused on how i would get a response id, and how to get it search all restaurants in a specific city i input in the search field.

https://developers.zomato.com/documentation#!/common/establishments

```
    Description    Parameter Type    Data Type
     user-key    
    (required)

    your API key

    header               string
    city_id    
    id of the city

    query               integer
    lat    
    latitude / longitude of any point within a city

    query                double
    lon    
    latitude / longitude of any point within a city

    query                  double
```

```
    var apiKey = 'd40175980577c1cb4df25d608886594b';
    var api = 'https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_id=259&entity_type=city&start=0&count=20'
    '
    var city = Bethesda;
    var url = api + city + apiKey;


function GetPosts(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        let output = '<h2>Get Posts</h2>';
        data.forEach(function(post) {

          output += `
              <div>
                  <h2>${post.title}</h2>
                  <p>${post.body}</p>

              </div>
              `;
        });
        document.getElementById('restaurant_results').innerHTML = output;

      })
  }
  document.querySelector('.submit-btn').addEventListener('click', GetPosts);
```

Comment: I think you are a bit confused about how API calls work and what you mean by POST. POST all caps mean HTTP Verb and Zomato API does not include a POST action (you can't add anything to their database according to their docs) based on your posts your trying to retrieve a list of restaurants in a given area?

Answer (score 0):

Zomato API documentation actually will craft a cURL request you can copy to try out for you. 
https://developers.zomato.com/documentation#!/restaurant/restaurant_0

In your case Zomato API generated:

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "user-key: XXXXXX" "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/locations?query=bethseda&count=10"
```

You can't just append an API key as you did above you need to include it in the header using the proper Header key as defined in their API docs.

```
fetch('https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/locations?query=bethseda&count=10', 
  {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
     "Accept": "application/json",
    "user-key": "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
  }}).then(function(response){
     return response.json(); 
 }).then(function(data){
   console.log(data);
 });
```

using `fetch` the documentation: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

if you want to be able to add a value and change the location, in your case chnage bethseda then you can make the url dynamic and change the city name before passing it into `fetch`

Please note how the method is GET, how I passed in the headers, and translated the `cURL` request into `fetch`